# Directory contents diff

Tags: file, directory

I'm looking for existing ideas / solutions to the problem of finding differences between two directories. Specifically how to identify files that might have been changed, renamed and moved.

A short list of things I've considered:

- try to pair up files missing in dir A
  with new files in dir b by using some
  heuristic such as 75% match in
  content. This just doesn't seem
  robust enough (problem cases include:
  significant changes in content,
  compression or encryption, possible
  multiple matches)
- use alternative data streams to add an id to each file. This would work      only on NTFS.
- add a header/footer to each file containing and id. There's no way to     guarantee header/footer will not       corrupt the file.
- ask for user input for each change to determine if file is indeed    deleted or simply moved. This is too     hard on user.
- require user to rename/move files only by using special commands    which    will keep track of such    changes. This    is too hard on user.
- setting up a file system watcher to catch changes on the fly. Several     issues (watcher must run at all       times, is platform specific...)

Any ideas welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for content match i recommend using some sort of distributed version control system such as `git`

it can pretty much detect all file operations such as copies, moves, renames, …

Comment: How does git detect that robustly?

Comment: it tracks contents and not files, so it can precisely detect changes in content, even over files. and if a file gets removed and another file with the same content gets added, then that's pretty much a rename

Comment: Do you have any insight into how it accomplishes that? It can't possibly compare such large texts directly...

Comment: what _large_ texts? what size are we talking about here? but basically it only checks for modifications if the hashes of objects/files changed

Comment: So if I rename, move and change file - will it be able to detect this "new" file is a derivative of the old one?

Comment: yes it will. if you want to inspect history with `git log` be sure to add `-C -M --follow` options, so you actually follow the history even over file rename boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

A possible, not perfect, solution would be a version control system such as svn or git. that way, all change history is available. But users have to use specific commands.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply calculate MD5/SHA-1 or oher hash calculation on the folder content?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

Build a list of files/folders for A and B.
Compare which are present in A but not in B.
Compare which are present in B nut not in A.
For those which are present in both A and B perform a hash calculation.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't too clear - I'd like to keep track of those changes not simply find out if two directories are different.

Answer (score 0):

Try [pkgdiff](http://lvc.github.io/pkgdiff/) to visualize differences between directories:

```
pkgdiff -d DIR-0/ DIR-1/
```

The tool detects added/removed/renamed/moved files and changed content. The tool is open-source, so you can configure your personal match rate to identify moved/renamed changed files.

[image]

[image]